# Can't find the data that's sended by using Ajax in the request object (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, json, ajax, express

I send a data object as in the code;

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var dataset;

function data () {

    dataset = {
        "name" : document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value,
        "pass" : document.getElementsByName("pass")[0].value,
        "email" : document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value,
        "birthday" : document.getElementsByName("birthday")[0].value,
        "agree" : false
    }

    if(document.getElementById("signupcheck").className.search("active") > -1) dataset.agree = true
    xhttp.open("POST", "/example", true);
    xhttp.send(dataset);
}
```

And I try to get that data on NodeJs as in the code;

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    console.log(__dirname);
})

app.post("/example", function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body)
})

var server = app.listen(8000,function(){

})
```

Ajax is working because I can see the req object on the console when I initialize the function. But the req object is so huge that doesn't fit into the terminal.

[image]

I can't find the data I send. How can I get the data?

Answer (score 1):

So I think the issue is with your request.

After running it locally I get:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or ArrayBuffer. Received an instance of Object
```

After taking a look at the documentation it confirms this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Could you try this?

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({dataset: dataset}))
```

or you could update your dataset object to

```
const dataset = {
    dataset: {
        name: document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value,
        pass: document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value,
        email: document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value,
        birthday: document.getElementsByName('birthday')[0].value,
        agree: false,
    },
}
```

and keep

```
xhttp.send(dataset)
```

Add the express json middleware so that you can access the body.

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const router = express.Router()

app.use(express.json())
```

```
console.log(req.body.dataset)
```

Comment: It returns "undefined".

Comment: Can you update the post with a console log of the req please. Are you using bodyParser with express?

Comment: I did it but I think it's useless because the object doesn't fit into the terminal.

Comment: When I write "req.body.dataset", I get two error that "POST http://localhost:8000/example 500 (Internal Server Error)" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onload". When I write "req.body", I get the result "undefined", I don't get any error.

Comment: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' - This has nothing to do with either the request or the route you've posted. You must have an error elsewhere when trying to update the html within a document.

You'll either have to post all of the code or find the issue yourself. I've tried this locally and it works.

Comment: And the internal server error means that the request is now working but your server (I assume express?) is getting an error when it receives that request and try's to process it.

Comment: I get the "Internal" error only when I write "req.body.dataset". And the editings we made don't fix the problem :/

Comment: Okay. I've added. My all NodeJs code is that much. And I've already posted the whole javascript code. Rest of those are HTML codes that I trigger the function. By the way, there is no mistake on the data itself, I print it on the browser console in data() function with Js and I can see it.

Comment: Right, think we're nearly there.. give that a go for me please